# OpenSUSE Setting path between shell formats

Tags: server-settings

I have 2 large commercial programs that work together come with fairly involved .cshrc scripts.  But whether I am in a bash/tsch/csh shell at start up, my initial path on startup is in bash format.  When I run the .cshrc scripts that set the paths (and variables) for the programs support files, the system ignores the paths set via the cshrc script.

Example from the echo $PATH command  Note, I get same results if I start up in a bash or csh shell.

initial path
/usr:/usr/bin

after cshrc
/usr:/usr/bin  /home/program1  /home/program2

since I can't alter their scripts, what can I do to change the path to 1 format?
Either:
/usr:/usr/bin:/home/program1:/home/program2
or
/usr usr/bin /home/program1 /home/program2

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In BOTH csh or sh varients PATH is an environment variable and will look identical.

You are confused with setting $path (notice lower case), these are local to the csh environment and will look differently.

FYI, setting environment variable on sh and csh varients are:

sh:       PATH='a;b;c;d;e';export PATH

csh:      setenv PATH 'a;b;c;d;e'
          -OR-
          path='(a b c d e)'